# SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog not executing code-behind

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a situation where I want to execute some code-behind and open a modal popup. I use a LinkButton  with an onClick event defined to do this, the code-behind execute but The popup doesn't  open.

code-behind

```
Page.ClientScript.registerstartupscript(this.gettype(),"","javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ url: '../Lists/GBE/NewForm.aspx', title: 'User Survey' }); return false;",true)
```

design

```
<asp:LinkButton onclick="LinkButton-click" runnat="serevr" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` will render a script block on the page. You don't need to add *javascript:* protocol prefix:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
  GetType(),
  <ScriptKey>,
  "SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ url: '../Lists/GBE/NewForm.aspx', title: 'User Survey' }); return false;",
  true);
```

This prefix is required if you want to execute javascript code in a `href` attribute of an `a` tag:

```
<a href="javascript:alert('hello world')">Test</a>
```

Comment: I have a linkbutoon . when user click lickbutton , I want to execute some code-behind then show popup

Comment: @niloo: yes, I just included what _javascript:_ is used for. Just omit _javascript:_ in your start up script.

Comment: Is there a javascript error? Does it work when display a simple alert instead of the showDialogCall?

Comment: there isn't error and execute code-behind but don't open popup

Comment: Does it work when display a simple alert instead of the showDialogCall?

Comment: <asp:LinkButton 
    ID="linkButton1" 
    runat="server" 
    Text="Something"
    OnClientClick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.ShowModalDialog({url:''}); return false;">
 </asp:LinkButton>
.. this code work